# Jquery show/hide div- minor tweak

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript that shows or hides a div when a link is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){               
               $('.show_hide').showHide({            
                    speed: 500,  // speed you want the toggle to happen 
                    changeText: 0, // if you dont want the button text to change, set this to 0
                    showText: 'View',// the button text to show when a div is closed
                    hideText: 'Close' // the button text to show when a div is open                                  
                });                 
            });

            (function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide',

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () {     
             // this var stores which button you've clicked
             var toggleClick = $(this);
             // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
             var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
             // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect



             $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
             // this only fires once the animation is completed
             if(options.changeText==1){
             $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
             }
              });

          return false;

        });

    };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The problem is, I have two such divs, but I only want one to be displayed at a time. So, if someone clicks on the link to display `div 2`, and `div 1` is already displayed, it should hide itself first before displaying `div2`.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="button"><a href="#" rel="#faq" class="show_hide">FAQs</a></div>
<div class="button"><a href="#" rel="#contact" class="show_hide">Contact</a></div>
<div id="faq" class="faq">FAQs here </div>
<div id="contact" class="faq">Contact form here </div>
```

I don't have any experience with JS/Jquery, but I tried adding this code, which didn't work:

```
             var otherDiv;

             if ($(this).attr('rel') == 'contact')
                otherDiv = 'faq';
             else
                otherDiv = 'contact';            

             if ($(otherDiv).is(":visible"))
                $(otherDiv).slideToggle(options.speed);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people use CSS classes as a place to store 'metadata'. When a div becomes visible, add a class to it like "toggledVisible" or whatever. When a new toggle is clicked, find all instances of "toggledVisible", hide them, and remove that class.

Alternatively, you always keep track of some sort of "currentlyVisible" object and toggle it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe jQuery ui accordion is an alternative?
HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#" rel="#faq">FAQs</a></h3>
    <div id="faq" class="faq">FAQs here</div>
    <h3><a href="#" rel="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
    <div id="contact" class="faq">Contact form here</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".accordion").accordion();
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szrhD/).

=== UPDATE ===

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: false
    });
});
```

Also see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szrhD/4/).

Comment: A bit heavy if other jQuery UI components won't be used. However, it's still a good point overall: there are already a million self-contained accordions out there; surely one of them will work!

Comment: I tried implementing the accordion, and it seems a really nice effect, however it won't work in this case for me because my contact form is relatively small, while the FAQs is huge. The accordion works best when all div's are roughly the same size. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: With setting the option `autoHeight` to `false` you can prevent this behaviour. See the [update](http://jsfiddle.net/szrhD/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this row in your click() function

```
$('.faq').not(this).hide();
```

This will hide all shown divs except the one you clicked.